# How does one avoid reallocation in a low-latency environment?

Tags: memory-management, trading, low-latency

In an order-book in a trading platform (low-latency environment) you need to store every order ID, at the very least to verify every order is unique. The number of order IDs you can receive in a trading day is unbounded. Apart from using historical data analysis, there is no number you can appropriately "guess" to preallocate your data structure. What schemes exist for avoiding intra-day order ID container reallocations?

Comment: Interview or homework question?

Comment: Good grief, neither. Why is this down-voted? It's a great question, one I have thought about off and on, on my own for a while.

Comment: I think it is a great question, but people here tend to be narrow minded in the way they view the world.

Answer (score 3):

> In an order-book in a trading platform (low-latency environment) you need to store every order ID, at the very least to verify every order is unique. The number of order IDs you can receive in a trading day is unbounded. Apart from using historical data analysis, there is no number you can appropriately "guess" to preallocate your data structure. What schemes exist for avoiding intra-day order ID container reallocations?

Good question. One solution is to use tree data structures where each branch is a separate heap allocation. This is how most purely functional data structures (e.g. `Set` and `Map` in OCaml and F#) work and it makes them incremental so insertion and deletion are always O(log *n*) worst case.